# Change Element name to that of one of its Attribute - XSLT/ XML

Tags: xml, xslt

Using XSLT I'd like to change an **XML Element name** to that of **one of its Attribute** (the element will only contain one attribute) and also to **remove the attribute**.

I have an XML document which looks like this:

```
<EVENTS>
  <EVENT TYPE="XXXXXX">
    <ID>1</ID>
    <STATUS>COM</STATUS>
  </EVENT>
  <EVENT TYPE="XXXXXX">
    <ID>2</ID>
    <STATUS>ACC</STATUS>
  </EVENT>
  <EVENT TYPE="YYYYYY">
    <ID>3</ID>
    <STATUS>COM</STATUS>
  </EVENT>
  <EVENT TYPE="ZZZZZZ">
    <ID>4</ID>
    <STATUS>COM</STATUS>
  </EVENT>
  <EVENT TYPE="XXXXXX">
    <ID>5</ID>
    <STATUS>DEL</STATUS>
  </EVENT>
</EVENTS>
```

I'd like to transform the document to looks like this:

```
<EVENTS>
  <XXXXXX>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <STATUS>COM</STATUS>
  </XXXXXX>
  <XXXXXX>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <STATUS>ACC</STATUS>
  </XXXXXX>
  <YYYYYY>
    <ID>3</ID>
    <STATUS>COM</STATUS>
  </YYYYYY>
  <ZZZZZZ>
    <ID>4</ID>
    <STATUS>COM</STATUS>
  <ZZZZZZ>
  <XXXXXX>
    <ID>5</ID>
    <STATUS>DEL</STATUS>
  </XXXXXX>
</EVENTS>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the `<xsl:element>` command, which in this case you'd use as in

```
<xsl:element name="{@TYPE}">
```

This uses an attribute value template, which allows string expressions inside curly braces.

Then arrange to not copy through the TYPE attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Excellent, thanks for your help! For completeness I used the following and it worked....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="EVENT">
      <xsl:element name="{@TYPE}">
          <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
     </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```